# Android Studio Flamingo - kaptGoogleDebugKotlin error

Tags: android

I have downloaded latest Android Studio Flamingo (2022.2.1 patch 2) but during the build of my project, I got the following:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGoogleDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

In the previous version of Flamingo, I did not have this problem. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After move to Android Studio: Flamingo, remember these imp few thing

1. Install/Update JDK 17 in your system and set as JAVA_HOME

example-> C:\jdk17\openjdk-17.0.6

2. set target JDK version 17

example:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

3. If you use DI framework Hilt or Dagger2 dependency then update with latest version

Example:

```
// Dagger DI
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.47'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.47'
```

4. If any other dependency or lib give such error while building just update with latest version
5. Please note Kotlin version should be 1.8.## and Gradle should be 8.0

Above 5 points will help you to resolve Flamingo and above version of Android studio issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed JDK version to the latest Amazon Corretto JDK and the problem went away.